# Strange behaviour of std::string

Tags: c++, string

I have this puny program.

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <string>
int main()
{
    std::string st = ('='+"10");
    std::cout<<st<<"-"<<st.c_str();
    return 0;    
}
```

What sort of output you expect without running it?

I am getting : `-`

I am running into such problems while using boost::spirit library and passing its output around as c-strings.

Am I missing something? I am using gcc 4.6.1 (ubuntu 10.10).

Comment: Note that adjacent string literals are combined by the compiler: `"=" "10"` becomes `"=10"` (C++03, § 2.13.4-3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
'=' + "10"
```

Probably does not do what you expect.  Rather than concatenating, it will "add" (arithmetically) the "ASCII" value of '=' to a pointer to the literal string "10", which is a buffer overrun and so invokes undefined behavior.

If you run your program under valgrind you will likely see it complain about this.

Instead, try:

```
std::string st = "=";
st += "10";
```

Comment: Thats odd! I thought `st += "10"` expands as `st = st + "10"`

Comment: @Dilawar: `'='` is a character, not a string. Also, adding c-strings won't concatenate them. Hence, John's use of `+=`.

Comment: You are right, those two things are equivalent.  But note that I wrote "=" rather than '=', and I added the C string literal "10" to a std::string, whereas you added it to a char.

Comment: Oh! That's why Haskell people make a lot of fuss about type matching.. :-|

Answer (score 1):

Try instead:

```
#include  <iostream>
#include  <string>
int main()
{
    std::string st = ('='+std::string("10"));
    std::cout<<st<<"-"<<st.c_str();
    return 0;
}
```

Note `"10"` is a `const char*` (pointer). Adding to it will increment the pointer using standard integer arithmetic and not concatenate a string.

Comment: I think compiler should raise a warning. I was compiling with -Wall .

Comment: There's no reason for a warning, incrementing a pointer is common practice in C/C++ and is valid in itself. The problem is you create an invalid address and pass that to the string constructor, which the compiler has no way of knowing about.

Comment: @TimGee: to be fair, the compiler could definitely warn about '='+"10" (incrementing a  pointer to a string literal by more than the string's length).  I'll not be surprised if no compilers do it yet, but they absolutely could.

Comment: Hmmm, slippery slope... What about (x + '=' + "10")? If x is negative, that could be valid. I don't think it's for the compiler to say myself.